# How to replace part of text

Tags: python

I am really new to coding so don't be harsh on me, since my question is probably basic. I couldn't find a way to do it.

I would like to learn how to create automatizated process of creating custom links.(Preferably in Python)
Let me give you example.

https://website.com/questions/**ineedtoreplacethis**.pdf

I have a database (text file) of names, one name one line 
(Oliver
David
Donald
etc.)

I am looking for a way how to automatically insert the name to the "ineedtoreplacethis" part of the link and create many many custom links like that at once.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack OverFlow, What have you tried till now?

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers, you really helped me!

Answer (score 3):

[f-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) is probably the way to go.

Here is an example:

```py
names = ['Olivier', 'David', 'Donald']

for name in names:
  print(f"{name}.txt")
```

Output:

```
Olivier.txt
David.txt
Donald.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using string concatenation as explained below. This is after you get the data from the text file, achieving that is explained in the later part of the answer.

```
a= "Foo"

b= "bar"
```

`a+b` will return

```
"Foobar"
```

In your case,

```
original_link = "https://website.com/questions/"

sub_link = "ineedtoreplacethis.pdf"

out = original_link + sub_link
```

The value of `out` will be as you required.

To get the `sub_link` from your `text file`, read the text file as:

```
with open("database.txt","r") as file:
    data= file.readlines() # Here I am assuming that your text file is CRLF terminated
```

Once you have the `data` , which is a list of all the values from your text file, you can iterate using `loops`.

```
for sub_link in data:
    search_link = original_link+sub_link 

    """Use this search_link to do your further operations"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a formatted string

```py
filename = "test.txt"
lines = []
with open(filename) as my_file:
    lines = my_file.readlines()
for i in lines:
    print(f"https://website.com/questions/{i}.pdf")
```

**EXPLAINATION:**

1. Read the txt file by a list of lines
2. Iterate over the list using For loop
3. Using formatted string print them

Answer (score 0):

Consider file `textFile.txt` as

```
Oliver
David
Donald
```

You can simply loop over the names in the file as

```
with open("textFile.txt", "r") as f:
    name_list = f.read().split('\n')
link_prefix = 'https://website.com/questions/'
link_list = []

for word in name_list:
    link_list.append(link_prefix + word + '.pdf')

print(link_list)
```

This will print output as (ie. contents of `link_list` is):

```
['https://website.com/questions/Oliver.pdf', 'https://website.com/questions/David.pdf', 'https://website.com/questions/Donald.pdf']
```

Comment: Sorry for asking but who will close the file?

Comment: @Roshan ohh, thanks, already done in edit. Btw downvote for not closing file?

Answer (score 0):

```
from pprint import  pprint as pp
import re

url = "https://website.com/questions/ineedtoreplacethis.pdf"

pattern = re.compile(r"/(\w+)\.pdf")  # search the end of the link with a regex
sub_link = pattern.search(url).group(1)  # find the part to replace

print(f"{sub_link = }")

names = ["Oliver", "David", "Donald"]  # text file content loaded into list

new_urls = []
for name in names:
    new_url = url.replace(sub_link, str(name))
    new_urls.append(new_url)

pp(new_urls)  # Print out the formatted links to the console
```